# “First Wednesday of the month at 9 AM” in cron?

Tags: cron

I'm trying to schedule a task to run on the “first Wednesday of the month at 9 AM” by using a cron expression.

The best I've got so far is `0 9 * * 3` which translates to “at 09:00 on Wednesday.” But that's *every* Wednesday, unfortunately.

Is it even possible to express that occurence in a cron expression?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/428807/run-a-cron-job-on-the-first-monday-of-every-month

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this syntax

```
0 9 1W * *
```

`1W` will specify the first Wednesday of the month.

**The answer below does not appear to work (at least according to some online tools)**

---

You can take advantage of the ability to specify multiple days in the 3rd parameter, like this:

```
0 9 1-7 * 3
```

Trying the expression in https://crontab.cronhub.io/, this is how the above gets described:

> At 09:00 AM, between day 1 and 7 of the month, and on Wednesday

You can be sure that one and only one of the first 7 days of the month will be Wednesday, and is also the first Wednesday of the month.

Comment: That's what I thought, too, but when I test `0 9 1-7 * 3` on https://crontab.guru/#0_9_1-7_*_3 it translates to “at 09:00 on every day-of-month from 1 through 7 and on Wednesday” and the next occurence is 2022-09-14 09:00:00 (i.e., next week). As if the “and” was really a “or”. Is that right? 

Comment: You may be right - that's painfully counter-intuitive but I've updated my answer with the correct solution. It appears cron has special support for this situation.

Comment: That said, trying `0 9 1-7 * 3` in a Python library seems to return the right thing. Maybe crontab.guru is not accurate, in this specific case.

Thanks for your edit, though. I learned about `1W`.

Comment: @gduverger what Python library are you using? croniter has `day_or` parameter, which controls whether there's an AND or OR relationship between the 3rd and the 5th field. It defaults to OR, same as UNIX cron.

Comment: @PēterisCaune I use https://github.com/josiahcarlson/parse-crontab. I'll check out Croniter. Thanks.

Comment: Something like this should also work in croniter, with the default `day_or` value: `0 9 * * 3#1`.

Comment: crontab.guru doesn't seem to understand `0 9 1W * *`

Answer (score 0):

I used [this](https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html) calculator to verify and generate cron expressions.

For your use case, it provides this.

```
0 0 9 ? * 4#1 *
```

Comment: Thanks. When I try `0 9 1-7 * 3` in the tool you linked, I get `Unexpected end of expression.` That's odd. And when I try `0 9 1W * *`, it reads `'W' option is not valid here. (pos=1)`. The expression you came up with seems to have 7 parts. I thought cron expressions only had 5. 